# connection reset issue with jquery submit() function

Tags: jquery, forms, file-upload, submit

I am uploading a big file (20 to 30 mb) with a form and the following jquery call:

```
$('#upload_form').submit();
```

The code works perfectly with small files. However, then the uploaded gets to 20 to 30 mb, the browser starts freaking out with the error message: **"The connection was reset"**

I am almost sure that it's not a server side problem, since the plain old form works fine:

```
<form></form>
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: You've ensured the `maximum_execution_time` isn't causing this?

Comment: not yet. I am trying now.

Comment: calling .submit() is no different than clicking a submit button if you aren't preventing the submit. Looks like a server issue to me.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I was googling 'maximum_execution_time', but I am not sure which one is what you had specified. Could you please sent me a link about it? thanks

Comment: @KevinB, You are right. The other form went to a different server. Would you please convert the comment into an answer so that I can vote you up?

Comment: I could, but... how does that answer the question? It did help point you in the right direction, but that wouldn't help future visitors.

Comment: Well... I find the most valuable sentence to be: "calling .submit() is no different than clicking a submit button if you aren't preventing the submit." To me, that's an good answer that force me to go back to check my preconditions. That's an legit answer alright.